# Codeigniter Facebook login 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter

So, I downloaded Codeigniter 2.1 and this library - https://puneetk.com/facebook-php-sdk-for-codeigniter/comment-page-1
I did all the things this tutorial was asking me for.
I wanted to check my website (it's a FB login script) and this error popped up - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icg4B.png
But that isn't the problem.
Problem is, that when I try to enter http://www.example.com/welcome/login this shows up - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je7kU.png
Why is that? I feel like I'm the only one with this problem. I've tried about 3-4 tutorials bet problem's the same. I tried latest Codeigniter's version too.
Any help?

Comment: This is an issue with your routes and mod_rewrite/htaccess, what is your default route? What are the contents of your .htaccess file?

Comment: Well, you see, I'm new to CI, this is for college. In root folder I don't have any .htaccess files. Although there's index.php. How do I manage those routes?

Comment: CodeIgniter explains how to set up the htaccess file at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html - Then as far as the routes there is a routes.php file in the config directory and you can read about setting up routes at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: You can pretty much use their example .htaccess file as is, as far as the routes your default route should be the controller/method you expect people to see as the "home page" so to speak

Comment: Big thanks to you. It just needed one .htaccess file inside the root folder. CI's pretty awesome, gotta learn all of it. Thanks again!

Comment: Anytime, best of luck :)